# Like button Title Link goes to facebook error page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm using the Like button in some pages and I notice today that when someone clicks on the like button it goes perfect to their timeline, it shows the image, description and the title I put on the OG meta tags, everything it's fine here, but... one of the links in the timeline of the user it's wrong.

The link in the image it's correct, the link in the url (gray small url just before the text) it's ok, but the link in the main title is: https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=193048140809145

With the text:
Sorry, this page isn't available
The link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed.

This issue it's occurring in a couple of sites, every site it's an individual site, they are for 2 different clients of mine, and both are showing the same link in the "liked" content title.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be a bug report for Facebook's API

Comment: Bug report from yesterday: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/490260747715286 – go subscribe to it to give it higher prio.